# MySQL Query with dynamic column name

Tags: mysql

I have a source table with these columns:

[image]

I also have a destination table like this:

[image]

The destination table has 1440 rows, with the minute column filled in (1 row for each minute in the day).

For each row in the source table, I need to fill in a "1" in the destination table for the appropriate channel (there are 10 channels total), for every minute between the StartTime and FinishTime.

I'm just doing this in MySQL Workbench (it's a one-time query).  What is my beast approach?

Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: Fill it in for start time or for end time or for everything in between?

Comment: How many channel columns are in the destination table? Just 9 or does it go onward?

Comment: What language are you using to access mysql? PHP?

Comment: See normalization. The b[e]st approach would be to dispense with the destination table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ChannelNumber
FROM source

while ($row = fetch_assoc()) {
    $channel_col = 'ch'.$row['ChannelNumber']
    $sql =  "
        UPDATE destination
        JOIN source ON StartTime = destination.minutes 
             AND source.ChannelNumber = $row[ChannelNumber]
        SET destination.$channel_col = 1
      ";
    query($sql);
}
```

Normally you have to be concerned about dynamically creating a string which becomes an SQL query to avoid SQL injection, but since all the data is coming from within your database it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I was hoping for a straight SQL solution, but this will do.  I created a small PHP script matching this that did the trick.

Comment: I'm reviewing this again, and I don't think it's doing what I need.  It seems it only updates the first minute that the channel is busy, is that right?  I need it updated for all minutes between the StartTime and EndTime.

Comment: I modified this to reflect my original SQL (which still gives me an error in a stored proc, even with @Aleksandar-Miladinovic 's suggestion) and got it to run.  I'll post my final script.

Comment: If the pseudo-code above got you to the answer that worked, please mark this as the accepted answer...

Comment: Shouldn't be the accepted answer, this is PHP, not Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MySQL solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PopulateDestinationTable()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CNumber INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE STime INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE FTime INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SourceTable INTO n;
SET i = 0;

WHILE i < n DO
    SELECT ChanelNumber FROM SourceTable LIMIT i, 1 INTO CNumber;
    SELECT StartTime FROM SourceTable LIMIT i, 1 INTO STime;
    SELECT FinishTime FROM SourceTable LIMIT i, 1 INTO FTime;

   SET @stat1 = CONCAT('UPDATE DestinationTable
                SET ', CONCAT('Ch', CNumber), ' = 1 WHERE minutes BETWEEN ? AND ?');

    PREPARE statement FROM @stat1;
    SET @p1 = STime;
    SET @p2 = FTime;
    EXECUTE statement USING @p1, @p2;

    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END$$
```

P.S. Don't forget to change Delimiter when create stored procedure :)

Answer (score -1):

I modified the PHP code from @peter-bowers to this and got it to work:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("ip", "user", "pass", "db");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$res = $mysqli->query("update scott_test set Ch1 = null, Ch2 = null, Ch3 = null, Ch4 = null, Ch5 = null, Ch6 = null, Ch7 = null, Ch8 = null, Ch9 = null, Ch10 = null");

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,DATE(TimeReceived),TimeReceived) AS StartTime, 
                CEIL(FaxDuration/60)+ TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,DATE(TimeReceived),TimeReceived) AS FinishTime,
                ChannelNumber
        FROM
                fax_received
        WHERE
                DATE(TimeReceived) = DATE((NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY))");

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

    $channel_col = 'ch'.$row['ChannelNumber'];
    $start_min = $row['StartTime'];
    $end_min = $row['FinishTime']; 
    $sql =  "UPDATE scott_test
                SET $channel_col = 1          
                WHERE minutes between ($start_min, $end_min);
    $mysqli->query($sql);

}
?>
```

Comment: This is a mysql question.